# How do I pass environment variables to a web extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to build a web extension that uses some AWS services and I don't want to upload API keys to git, however, I don't seem to be able to pass my API keys in the usual way. For example:

If I run the command `IDENTITY_POOL_ID=<id_pool_id> web-ext run` I usually expect the variable to be available in `process.env.IDENTITY_POOL_ID`, however, `process.env` is empty.

I've also tried adding a .env file to the root of the directory with the web extension.

Comment: Did you find any useful workarounds for this in development? The extension runs "client side" so I don't expect `process.env` to work but I still want to be able to set some configuration during development that is not checked into git as you say and then have different config for build (production.)

Answer (score 0):

Because the extension is running "client side" `process.env` is not available. The extension running in a browser doesn't have access to environment variables. Instead in this case you want the extension to use `browser.storage` and have the user (you maybe) set the value on install of the extension in the options page.

e.g. here is an `options.js` file;

```
function saveOptions(e) {
  var api_key = document.querySelector("#api_key").value
  browser.storage.local.set({"api_key": api_key}).then(restoreOptions)  
  e.preventDefault();
}

function restoreOptions() {
  browser.storage.local.get("api_key").then(function(data) {
    if (typeof data['api_key'] != 'undefined') {
      var api_key = data['api_key']
      document.querySelector("#api_key").value = api_key
    }
  })

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restoreOptions)
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", saveOptions)
```

And here is the corresponding `options.html`;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Options</titlE>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <label for="api_key">API Key:</label>
    <input type="text" id="api_key">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
  <script src="options.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```